# data not saving permanently in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I created a simple program that will accept input then stores the data inputted in the database.
I used a local ms sql service-based database  in vs 2013. The program runs perfectly and saves
the data inputted in the database. The problem is whenever I would show table data the data that I recently
inputted is gone. But when I modify the connection and set database file location and choose the database file in
"\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\locald\locald\bin\Debug\dbs.mdf" and when I input a new data the data is saved and
I can finally see the data in Inputted in the database. Why is it that the data is only stored when I
modify the connection and set the location in "\bin\Debug" folder. The default location of the database file
is in "\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\locald\locald\dbs.mdf" which is the defualt directory of the database that
does not store the data I inputted. And another thing, I set my database "Copy to Output Directory"
property to "Copy if newer" because the default value of it which is "Copy Always" just saves the latest data I inputted
and overwrites the second to the latest input that I inputted. How can I resolve this and make my database store data
permanently even if the connection is just in default location folder of the database?? Is there something that
I am missing?? Please Help thanks...

Here is the codes that I've used in my program:

Codes for my save button:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string f = textBox1.Text;
        int a = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        SqlConnection conn = locald.DB.GetSqlConnection();
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=f;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@age", SqlDbType.Int).Value=a;
        cmd.CommandText = @"savetotblinfo";
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch(SqlException err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Class that I created for my database connection:

```
public class DB
{
    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["locald.Properties.Settings.localdConnectionString"].ToString();

            SqlConnectionStringBuilder sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connStr);
            sb.ApplicationName = ApplicationName ?? sb.ApplicationName;
            sb.ConnectTimeout = (ConnectionTimeout > 0) ? ConnectionTimeout : sb.ConnectTimeout;

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
    public static string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public static int ConnectionTimeout { get; set; }
    public static SqlConnection GetSqlConnection()
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        cnn.Open();
        return cnn;
    }
}
```

stored procedure I used:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.savetotblinfo
    @fname varchar(300),
    @age int
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT INTO tblinfo
VALUES (@fname,@age)    
RETURN 0
```

And this what I did for in project properties in the setting option:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried  `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", <directory-of-db>);` ?

Comment: No. If will use this, where I will I put this code? Sorry I'm just new to c#.net..

Comment: Try setting it to Never Copy. What's happening is that in your base project folder is a copy of the database file that is altered as you are designing tables and such during development. When you run, it is copying that into your bin|debug/release folder and it is always empty. By stating never copy, you would then have to alter any database designs in the version that resides in the bin|debug/release folder for them to show. Otherwise, you could copy your design back from the base project, again, that will have no data. Copy if Newer should be fine but will overwrite if you make any changes.

Comment: I've set it now to "Do not Copy" but there is an error occuring. The error is this:

"An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file Projects\\locald\\locald\\bin\\Debug\\dbs.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."

Comment: I've read this article just now in here :

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2012/05/dealing-with-local-databases-or-why-your-updates-dont-stick.aspx

is this problem some kind of a glitch in VS 2013??? If I'm wrong please enlighten me.. thanks.

Comment: If you want your application to use the database in locald rather than locald\bin\debug, then setting DataDirectory before you open the DB connection should do it. The default behavior for non-ASP.NET projects with local databases like this does seem a little odd but I assume it's ensure you have some sort of empty 'reference' database that you can ship with your product (rather than relying on EF to create the DB and schema).